# How to get a specified object reffering to a value inside (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set a javascript property object with some values of another property object from the same instance. Actualy I have the object below:

```
var PLAYER = {
slides: {
{ slide_id: 60, slide_content: 'content for slide 1', type: 'slide' },
{ slide_id: 65, slide_content: 'content for slide 2', type: 'slide' },
{ slide_id: 70, slide_content: 'content for slide 3', type: 'slide' },
{ qId: 4, question: 'question text', after_slide: 70, type: 'question' },
{ slide_id: 74, slide_content: 'content for slide 5', type: 'slide' }
},
currentSlide: 0,
container: false,
currentCarouselSlide: 0,
carousel: {},
}
```

Now I have an array like this:

```
var carouselRandomSlides = [60,70];
```

Later in my `PLAYER` object I have a function that ar feetching my slides like this

```
<script>
    fetchSlide: function(index,increment) {
    var _this = this;
    $.post('/player/fetchSlide', { slideContent: _this.slides[index] }, function(response){
            increment ? (increment == 'increase' ? _this.currentSlide++ : _this.currentSlide--) : null; 
    $(_this.container).html(response);
    if (_this.slides[index].qId) {
    this.questions.correctAnswer = _this.slides[index].correct_answer;
    $.each(_this.slides[index].carousel, function(i,slideId) {
    _this.carousel[++i] = _this.slides[slideId];
    });
    } 
    else {
    _this.questions.correctAnswer = false;
    _this.carousel = {};
    } 
    console.log(_this.carousel);
    });     
    },
</script>
```

in this function I'm testing if the current slide is a question `if (_this.slides[index].qId)` and if it is, then I dinamically try to create a carousel that will contain slides `60` and `70` . There can be no slides to play or more than two.. this doesn't depends on me. This below code part should do the trick

```
$.each(_this.slides[index].carousel, function(i,slideId) {
    _this.carousel[++i] = _this.slides[slideId];
});
```

but `_this.slides[slideId]` is the same with `_this.slides[60]` and actualy i need `_this.slides[1]`

How could i get the object that contain `slide_id: 60` in the above `$.each()` function?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to make `Player.slides` an object containing unnamed objects? Looks like it should be an array to me. That could be your whole problem right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var PLAYER = {
   slides: [
      { slide_id: 60, slide_content: 'content for slide 1', type: 'slide' },
      { slide_id: 65, slide_content: 'content for slide 2', type: 'slide' },
      { slide_id: 70, slide_content: 'content for slide 3', type: 'slide' },
      { qId: 4, question: 'question text', after_slide: 70, type: 'question' },
      { slide_id: 74, slide_content: 'content for slide 5', type: 'slide' }
   ]
```

`PLAYER.slides` should be an array.

You could then use `$.grep()` to get the correct item.

```
function getSlideById(id){
  return $.grep(PLAYER.slides, function(el,i){
    return el.slide_id === id;
  })[0]; // returns array so first item [0]
}
```

Read more about [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work to me.. but this seems to works fine 

    `$.each(_this.slides[index].carousel, function(i,slideId) {
     // _this.carousel[++i] = _this.slides[slideId];
     $.each(_this.slides, function() {
      this.slide_id === slideId ? _this.carousel[++i] = this : null;
     });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `Player.slides`, you probably want to work with an array. Something like this:

**Note:** *this javascript code will not work as is, you will need to modify it.*

```
var PLAYER = {
  slides: {
    [ slide_id: 60, slide_content: 'content for slide 1', type: 'slide' ],
    [ slide_id: 65, slide_content: 'content for slide 2', type: 'slide' ],
    [ slide_id: 70, slide_content: 'content for slide 3', type: 'slide' ],
    [ qId: 4, question: 'question text', after_slide: 70, type: 'question' ],
    [ slide_id: 74, slide_content: 'content for slide 5', type: 'slide' ]
  },
  currentSlide: 0,
  container: false,
  currentCarouselSlide: 0,
  carousel: {},
}
```

For getting the insides, you can use the javascript `Array.indexOf(content)` method.

Good luck.

Comment: You have it backwards. `PLAYER.slides` should be an array of objects, not an object of arrays.